Android Kotlin project SerialPort library not found
When I run "sync with Gradle files" it can't find this serialport library:
implementation 'com.deemons.serialport:serialport:1.2.0'

here is an image:

Since this is inherited project, not maintained for a long time and I am just trying to build it and run, but it fails on this first step.
Is there any workaround for this? project is heavily dependent on this lib

The library com.deemons.serialport:serialport:1.2.0 has last been released in June of 2018.
It doesn't look like it is maintained and since it was hosted in JCenter, it needed to be migrated to mavenCentral.
This is because JCenter is shutting down
Your options are to:

Find the source code of the library and work on it so it is up to date with the current API levels
Find more recent alternative libraries that help you do what you are after

